# Webbrowser control (Local Folder view) - disable right click?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm using Webbrowser control as Windows Explorer (only a temporary solution) for viewing my directories, and I want to disable Windows right-click context menu. Anybody knows about some API that might do this ?

P.S.: "IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled" property doesn't work for Local paths (and no other property).

Comment: This is weird, cause i've put `IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled=False` and it does what you want.. ( with local folder! )

Comment: Maybe we really don't understand each other. Put like this in your Form_Load : "WebBrowser1.Navigate("D:\")". Then try setting "IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled=False" and right click in Webbrowser control. In my case I still get Windows right-click menu.I tried in 2 different PC's, same outcome. Maybe you have set some other properties ?

Comment: Hmmm.. i wasn't thnking like that. If you try `WebBrowser1.Navigate("D:\SomeImage.jpg")` you can see that it works properly..
I gotta try something else.